# Relating Binomial Coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

This question popped up in my revision sheet, and was just wondering on how to do it (this is high-school math by the way, so nothing too complicated please)

"Expand $(x+(1-x))^n$, and use this to prove: 
$nC0+nC1+nC2+...+nCn=2^n$"

I literally have no idea on how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$1=(x+(1-x))^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$
Now let $x=\frac12$. Can you take it frome here?

Comment: You're welcome.